# Marcar apenas um radiobutton de cada linha

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, html5

Tenho uma lista, onde por linha irei marcar o radiobutton informando: TEM, NÃO TEM, AVARIADO.

Como eu faço e qual a forma correta de enviar isso para o BD MySQL para depois na tela de edição capturar?

> Lembrando que essas `<tr>` vão estar em um php foreach para listalas
>
> Como fazer para enviar ao banco de dados para depois reutilizar na tela de editar.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NOME</th>
        <th>TEM</th>
        <th>NÃO TEM</th>
        <th>AVARIADO</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Documento</td>
        <td><label><input name="group[]" type="radio" checked /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input name="group[]" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input name="group[]" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Manual</td>
        <td><label><input name="group[]" type="radio" checked /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input name="group[]" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input name="group[]" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vidro</td>
        <td><label><input name="group[]" type="radio" checked /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input name="group[]" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input name="group[]" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Não está faltando colocar isto em um `<form>` para ser enviado após um clique em um botão por exemplo?

Comment: Olá Thiago, aqui eu tenho o `<form>`, mas nesse post não faz diferença. Veja que só consigo marcar 1 no total de radio. Onde o certo seria marcar 1 por linha.

Comment: Isto não é por causa do `name=group[]`?

Comment: Não porque tenho que mandar tudo para a mesma tabela do BD

Comment: Se tiverem com o mesmo nome estão no mesmo grupo.

Comment: Mas você deve capturar separado. Olha aqui: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OYgajB

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi bem mas a propriedade `name` indica a qual grupo o `<input::radiobutton>` pertence.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NOME</th>
        <th>TEM</th>
        <th>NÃO TEM</th>
        <th>AVARIADO</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Documento</td>
        <td><label><input name="group1" type="radio" checked /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input name="group1" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input name="group1" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Manual</td>
        <td><label><input name="group2" type="radio" checked /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input name="group2" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input name="group2" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vidro</td>
        <td><label><input name="group3" type="radio" checked /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input name="group3" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input name="group3" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Augusto, obrigado. E para enviar ao MySQL, devo enviar para a mesma tabela como array? Como devo fazer essa parte de envio ao banco de dados?

Comment: Isso tinha que estar num `<form>` para submeter um `HTTP GET` ou `HTTP POST`, ou ser enviado usando um objeto `XMLHttpRequest ` por meio de código javascript.

Comment: Aqui esta dentro do form.

Comment: Coloca o código do back end, senão não dá para lhe ajudar.

Comment: Fiz a atualização colocando esse ponto.

Comment: No geral é o atributo `action` do `<form>` tem que estar assim, caso o back end seja php,`<form action='/minhapagina.php'>`

Answer (score 1):

Sobre o motivo do Radio não funcionar, é o que o Augusto já disse. Você não pode usar o mesmo nome para todos os botões e não existe a necessidade do nome ser um vetor no seu código apresentado, pois apenas um único valor vai ser vinculado a cada tag name.

Sobre como salvar no banco, primeiramente precisa de um form com um action e um method, de preferencia esse action direcionando para outra pagina .php

```
<form method="POST" action="salvaNoBanco.php">
 .
 .
 .
     // Botões de Radio
 .
 .
 .
    <input type="submit" value="Confirmar">
</form>
```

Agora na página do meu exemplo(salvaNoBanco.php), você precisara receber esses valores do Radio. Supondo que os nomes sejam documento, manual e vidro, você salva no banco da seguinte maneira:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO MinhaTabela(documento, manual, vidro)
VALUES ('{$_POST['documento']}', '{$_POST['manual']}', '{$_POST['vidro']}')";

if ($conexao->query($query) === TRUE) {
     echo "Salvo com sucesso!";
} else {
     echo "Error: " . $query. "<br>" . $conexao->error;
}
```