# Dois input radio marcando na mesma form/header padding bugado

Tags: html, css, html5

tudo bem? Então, estou com um problema, tenho um formulário com 2 radios... É pra marcar um ou outro, mas tá dando para marcar os dois...

Aqui está ele:

```
<div class="budget-wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>Solicitando orçamento</h1>
    </header>
    <form method="post" id="form-radio" name="form-radio">
    <div class="blank">
        <h1>Para quem é o projeto?</h1>

        <div class="form-radio">
        @csrf
        <fieldset>
            <h1 style="width:auto"><input type="radio" id="empresa" name="empresa" value="empresa" form="form-radio" >Empresa </h1>
            <h1>&nbsp<u>o</u>u</h1>
            <h1><input type="radio" id="pessoal" name="pessoal" value="pessoal" form="form-radio" >Pessoal</h1> 
        </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <button type="submit"><h1>Continuar</h1></button>
    </footer>
    </form>
</div>
```

O que pode estar acontecendo? Em outros formulários com radios, está acontecendo a mesma coisa...

O problema do header, é que se colocar `padding-right:30%` ele não fica o padding, ai tenho que colocar no elemento que está em right, `margin-right:60%;float:right;` o padding-left funciona normalmente, com `30%`... O que pode ser?

```
/*PADDING DIVS*/
.div-padding{padding-left:30%;padding-right:30%;}

/*HEADER*/
.header{z-index:3;background-color:#343434;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0px;height:75px;padding-left:30%;}
.header button{margin-top:26px;margin-right:60%;float:right;position:relative;background-color:#5f06d9;border:none;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;}
.header button h1{cursor:pointer;padding:5px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;color:#fff;}
.header button h1 i{margin-right:10px}
.header button h1 a{color:#fff;text-decoration:none}



<header class="header">
    <a href=""><img src="/css/images/logo.png" class="logo" rel="logo"></a>
    <button id="budget-btn"><h1><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>Solicitar orçamento</h1></button>
</header>
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Bem-vindo. Faça um [tour] para entender melhor como o Stack Overflow funciona. Sugiro que você divida em duas perguntas distintas os problemas do seu código, essa para tratar a questão do `input=radio` e outra para o problema relacionado ao `padding/margin`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Marcar apenas um radiobutton de cada linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/384886/marcar-apenas-um-radiobutton-de-cada-linha)

Answer (score 2):

O atributo [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#name) dos elementos devem ser iguais para que o mesmo possa controlar qual opção está selecionada. No seu caso, cada um está com um nome: `pessoal` e `empresa`, por isso não funciona.

```html
A <input name='selecao' value='A' type='radio'><br>
B <input name='selecao' value='B' type='radio'>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado, resolveu meu erro.